# How to get real number of likes, despite of diffrences in URL

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get number of likes of specified URL.

```
/http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.example.com
```

However, there is a problem if URL looks like:

```
/http://www.example.com/page.php?param1=aaa&param2=bbb
```

Then Facebook treats it like:

```
/http://www.example.com/page.php
```

I tried to use urlencode(), but then I can get the wrong number, because for Facebook urls:

```
/http://www.example.com/page.php
```

and

```
/http://www.example.com/page.php?sort=by_date
```

are two diffrent pages.

On the other hand, I cannot remove all GETs, because they sometimes matters, e.g.

```
/http://www.example.com/?article=123
```

Is there any solution of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix this by inputting the URL for the like botton. all you need to do is build the url and then pass it on. here is a php example :

```
$mainURL = "http://www.example.com/";
$articleID = $r['id']; // GET THE ARTICLE ID FROM DB OR SOMETHING
$finalURL = $mainURL . "?article=" . $articleID;

// here you can wget the facebook api and see the number of likes etc using $finalURL
```

Comment: Your solution works only when I exactly know how url should looks like. What if urls are from various websites and each of them is diffrent?

Comment: well are you going to know anything about the structor of the URLs?? if the first GET value is the only one that matters or anything like that?

Comment: No, these are just random links. It can be http://www.google.com or http://www.example.com/a/?a=a&aaa=bbb . I need a general rule what to do with urls

Answer (score 0):

Use this Facebook API method

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count from link_stat where url='http://www.google.com/'&format=json
```

Result:

```
[{"total_count":5328613,"like_count":934962,"comment_count":969801,"share_count":3423850,"click_count":265614}]
```

.

```
  $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $call);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return json_decode($output);
}

$fb_likes = reset( get_fb_likes("http://www.cnn.com") );
echo $fb_likes->total_count;
echo $fb_likes->like_count;
echo $fb_likes->comment_count;
echo $fb_likes->share_count;
echo $fb_likes->click_count;
?>
```

via http://halgatewood.com/get-number-of-facebook-likes-for-a-url/